# Крестная мать кому или кого?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

Крестная мать кому или кого?
Крестная мать дочерей или дочерям?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Крестная мать*, так же как и просто *мать*, может быть чей-либо матерью или матерью кому-либо (Кому война, а кому мать родна).

Такие выражения как "мать дочерей" или "жена мужа" неудачны, внутренне плеонастичны по сути. Можно сказать "крестная мать *моих* дочерей", "крестная мать *моим* дочерям".